# Flutter ClipRect and Align : how to compute the Alignment values

Tags: flutter

I want to display part of an image (a rectangle of 128 * 128 inside this image which is 512 * 512) in a rectangle in  Flutter app.
Like this:
[image]

I want to select a specific zone in the source image, here from x=115, y=12 with width=128,height=128.

So here's my Flutter code to do this:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var myWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: Container(
            width: myWidth,
            height: myWidth,
            color: Colors.yellow,
            child: FittedBox(
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
              child: ClipRect(
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment(2.0*115.0 / 512.0 - 1, 2.0*12.0 / 512.0 -1.0),
                  widthFactor: 0.25,
                  heightFactor: 0.25,
                  child: Image.network(
                      "https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/baboon.png"),
                ),
              ),
            )));
  }
}
```

I *suppose* that the widthFactor and heightFactor represent the percentage of the original image I want to display - so here, because I want to display 128 pixels, it's 25% of the original width/height.
However, I just can't figure out out to calculate the values for the alignment.
First I tried for x :

```
 alignment: Alignment(2.0*115.0 / 512.0 - 1, 2.0*12.0 / 512.0 -1.0),
```

Which *almost* gives the desired result, but not quite, see below:

[image]

I tried many other combinations to calculate the Alignment values and read all I could find with the help of Google... Is this even possible to accomplish this with a ClipRect and an Align?

Any help is welcome ;-)

NOTE : I *don't* want to crop the original image (and hence produce a new image), I want to keep it as downloaded to avoid having N copies of the same bitmap in memory. What I want is a specific view on the image - something that is absolutely trivial to do with OpenGL/DirectX and UV coordinates for example, but not so with Flutter.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that...There's really no simpler way to achieve the desired result?

Comment: Based on @pskink comment, I've implemented a simple solution. It uses the additional package network_to_file_image to load images usable in a canvas.

Comment: If you have a solution then you should post it in the answer section instead of an edit and then mark it as correct. Do not add SOLVED to the title of your post.

Comment: Thank you @eyllanesc. I thought I had used the answer section, but I probably missed a step somewhere. Will do better next time.

Answer (score 1):

Based on pskink comment, provided a working solution in the original post.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:network_to_file_image/image_for_canvas.dart';
import 'package:network_to_file_image/network_to_file_image.dart';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var myWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    User user = User(
      filename: null,
      url: "https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/baboon.png",
    );

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: Container(
          width: myWidth,
          height: myWidth,
          color: Colors.yellow,
          child: CustomPaint(
              painter: ImagePainter(user, loadCallback: (_, __, ___) {
            setState(() {});
          })),
        ));
  }
}

class ImagePainter extends CustomPainter {
  final User user;
  final LoadCallback<User> loadCallback;

  ImagePainter(
    this.user, {
    required this.loadCallback,
  });

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    canvas.save();
    canvas.drawRect(Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, size.width, size.height),
        Paint()..color = Colors.lightGreenAccent);
    canvas.restore();

    var imageForCanvas = _imageForCanvas();
    ui.Image? image = imageForCanvas.image(user);

    if (image != null) {
      canvas.save();
      canvas.drawImageRect(
        image,
        Rect.fromLTWH(
          12,
          12,
          256,
          256,
        ),
        Rect.fromLTWH(
          0,
          0,
          size.width,
          size.height,
        ),
        Paint()..imageFilter = ui.ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: .5, sigmaY: .5),
      );
      canvas.restore();
    }
  }

  ImageForCanvas<User> _imageForCanvas() => ImageForCanvas<User>(
        imageProviderSupplier: (User user) => NetworkToFileImage(
          file: null,
          url: user.url,
        ),
        keySupplier: (User user) => user.url!,
        loadCallback: loadCallback,
      );

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}

class User {
  final String? filename;
  final String? url;

  User({
    this.filename,
    this.url,
  });
}
```